# How to perform a Dagger 2 Constructor, Method, Field Injection?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm practicing dagger 2 for a week now, I just want to know the difference of these injections(**constructor**, **method**, **field**), and where should I use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Constructor:** whenever you've the possibility to do so (when you have access to the constructor, for example, with your presenters if you use MVP pattern).

**Field:** when you don't have access to the constructor, for exemple when injecting in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

**Method:** an `@Inject` annotated method will be executed by Dagger as soon as the construction call has finished. We usually use it when we want to pass class instance itself (`this` reference) to injected dependencies.

Read [this](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-the-api/) for more informations and examples of use cases.

Comment: Thank you for you help.